# Appengine: help needed in designing my entities to be more scalable yet inexpensive

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

As an e.g. consider it as online survey site.

**Entities**:

`Survey (created with questions, answers)`

`Respondent` (who takes surveys in *parallel*. *huge* in no.)

- `survey id`
- `List` (`question id`, `answer id`)

**Problem:**

Need to get summary of responses i.e. for any particular `survey`, for any `question`, no. of respondents who chose answer 1 vs 2 vs 3 (say) 
Summary to be retrieved cheaply i.e. with less calls as possible

This code is *just* to help you get more understanding:

```
Survey sampleSurvey = ..
// get all respondents of above survey
List<Respondent> r = getAllRespondents(sampleSurvey);
// update summary per chosen question, answer
for each respondent:
    List<QuestionAnswer> qa = respondent.getChosenAnswers()
    for each chosen question, answer:
          // increments corresponding answer count by 1
          sampleSurvey.updateSummary(question.getId(), answer.getId()) 
// summary update done

// process summary
Summary summary = sampleSurvey.getSummary();
for each available question, answer:
    print 'No. of respondents who chose answer %s for question %s are %s' % (answer.text(), question.text(), answer.count())
```

**My thoughts**:

a. Creating a summary entity for each survey as and when a respondent takes the survey by updating the counters inside summary `entity(Q1 -> A1 -> 4, Q1 -> A2 -> 222,...).`

Pros: get summary by reading just 1 entity; cheap

Cons: since huge no. of respondents take same survey in parallel, it means datastore contention; sharding a solution? no. of shards to be dynamic depending on no. of respondents for surveys.

b. Querying the count against indexes. With my little knowledge about appengine indexing, i dont know 
how the index will be formed for above Respondent entity and how large it will be. Also am worried about no. of those extra writes needed for indexes, index exploding might happen? 
query should be something like
`select count(*) from Respondent where surveyId=xx and questId=yy and ansId=zz`

Any other better solutions? And what about above? which one you recommend and why. Thanks a lot for looking and for your suggestions. Ping if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on two main factors:

1. Do you know the queries you'll want to run ahead-of-time? (i.e. while the respondents are answering, as opposed to slicing up the data later.)
2. How many respondents do you expect? (Both # and rate.)

If you don't know the queries ahead-of-time, then I think the best you can do is fetch all the entities and compute the information you need. (And then cache that, perhaps, in another entity or memcache or both.) If you have a lot of respondents, you might have to do this computation on a [backend](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/) or via a [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) to avoid hitting the request timeout/quotas. If you have a truly enormous amount of data, you might even consider [Mapreduce](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/), which is currently experimental and Python-only.

If you do know the queries ahead-of-time, then I think your approach of a single entity is on the right track. You can a standard [sharded counter technique](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) to reduce contention if you expect more than about one write per second. If you don't expect more than that, you can just use a single entity group.

If you only expect around one write per second, with possible spikes above this, another option would be to use a single entity but use a task in a task queue to update its counter asynchronously; you can throttle the task queue rate to reduce contention, so long as you won't be creating tasks faster than it can complete them. This might be easier to write, especially if you have lots of statistics to compute, though I think the sharded counters technique above is ultimately more scalable.

Comment: First thanks for a good answer. As to the factors listed a. yes i know most of the queries. survey summary to be showed in real time so this means while respondents are answering (and some data are yet to be persisted), summary to reflect just whatever we already (currently) have in datastore. b. this is tricky. respondents can be few for some surveys or it can very well be tens of thousands to millions. Scalability is very important for me here.

Comment: Now reg. answers a. i thought abt this. querying all entities doesn't appear to me cheap though its scalable (reasons: considering new pricing for datastore operations; also viewing summary for survey is a very common use case; will keep an eye on Mapreduce but now am in java :(; for this approach computing in backend is the only way as no. of respondents can be very large but apart from above probs this also affects real time summary viewing)

Comment: (contd.) b. good that sharding approach is good for this problem. 1 or 100 or 1000 or 50000 (say) respondents can take same survey in parallel, so not sure how feasible it will be to implement a dynamic sharding. Also can you comment about indexing that i mentioned? is there a chance to explode/do you foresee huge indexes? any idea.

Comment: If you expect to re-compute some stat over and over, you can certainly cache it in an entity or memcache. You might also be able to mark entities as "counted" and just loop over non-counted ones when re-computing that stat. Dynamic sharing should be fairly easy with the code I linked to; just make more shards when you encounter contention. (i.e. transaction failures)

Comment: As for the index, I believe that `select count(*)` is nearly as expensive as fetching those entities; ([ref](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_count)) it still has to count each one individually. You'd also be making an entity per answer, rather than an entity per taken survey; my gut is that it would end up costing more, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Mapreduce is available for java, too.

Comment: @NickJohnson do you have a link for those docs? I can only find the python version: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/

Comment: @JesseRusak http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava

Answer (score 1):

Updating a summary with every write is not practical, since you'll quickly run into contention issues; counting the results dynamically will be extremely inefficient. In this case, you're better off computing aggregates using a batch process such as mapreduce - just write a task that scans over all the survey answers and accumulates the relevant statistics, and run this task periodically.

Comment: Thanks Nick. MapReduce sounds promising but am worried processing too much entities (and hence draining my quotas) each time while generating report. I might also miss real time summary viewing. What do you feel about dynamic sharding? if no other go, then mapreduce seems to be way.

Comment: @Hari Sharding adds a lot of complexity. I'm not sure what you mean by 'dynamic' sharding. If you're concerned about duplicate work, you could write your own bulk task that only fetches new entities to add them to the aggregate - or you could use a pull queue to achieve the same effect.